# Custom post type as a category, for another custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I have custom post type called 'Porjects', and I have second custom post type called 'Clients'. Now, I want to 'Clients' be category for 'Projects'. How can I do this? Clients is custom post type not taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

I did the exact same thing (connecting projects & clients) using the [Advanced Custom Fields plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/). I did this because my clients needed custom fields as well (logo, website URL).

I used the '[Post object](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/field-types/post-object/)' field for my project page, which will create a dropdown of your clients.
Some editing of your template is required (to show your client info near a project), but the documentation on the plugin's site is really good.

Comment: I can't use plugin, because I make plugin... but thanks for your willingness to help.

Comment: Did you find a solution .if yes then please share here